# Removing entries in an ArrayList

Tags: java

I am trying to traverse an ArrayList and remove all elements of the list that are empty. However, a simple for-loop traversal will not work because as I remove, the indices shift and I end up skipping elements. How do I account for this?

Comment: It's not really clear for me to get your issue. Can you post your code and the error logs?!

Comment: There is no error but I will post code

Comment: What is the type of your `ArrayList` ?

Comment: It is an arraylist of strings

Comment: `(terms.get(k)).length() < 1` it is not `null`.  They are just non-null empty `String`

Comment: `null` and `empty Strings` are not the same fyi. do you want to remove a length of String less than `1`?

Comment: Oh yes that makes sense but it would not change that it cannot access the end right?

Comment: what do you mean by "cannot access the end"?

Comment: to remove elements from a list, simply iterate the list from the end instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a lot of ways you can do. Here are just some examples

## Adjust the index

The problem for your iteration is, when you remove element from certain index, the elements following it will be shifted up.

So,

```
for(int k = 0; k < terms.size(); k++) {
   if((terms.get(k)).isEmpty()) {  // use isEmpty() plesae
      terms.remove(k--);  // move k back 1 element, so it points to 
                          // correct index after increment of for loop
   }
}
```

## Use iterator

IIRC `ArrayList`'s iterator supports `remove()`, so you can do

```
for (Iterator<String> itr = terms.iterator(); itr.hasNext(); ) {
    if (itr.next().isEmpty()) {
        itr.remove();
    }
}
```

## Do the filtering, and construct a new array list.

It may be easiest if you do not really need in-place removal

(Assume you are using Java 8)

```
terms = terms.stream().filter(s -> ! s.isEmpty())
              .collect(Collectors.toList());

// or create another list for result, then 
// terms.clear(); terms.addAll(tempList);
// if you need to change content of terms instead
```

Answer (score 0):

Every time `remove` is called, the size of the ArrayList shrinks, so the destructive loop won't work. If the assumption of all empty items placed at the end is guaranteed, I think you can instead search for the index of the first inner empty item then call `subList` on the found index.

```
int k;
for(k = 0; k < terms.size(); k++)
{
    if((terms.get(k)).length() < 1) break;
}
return terms.subList(0, k)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know *exactly* what you want to remove, then you have two options.

You can either use `List#removeAll` to remove all elements in a dummy collection that you control, which has the disadvantage of adding overhead for a list that you never use...

```
stringList.removeAll(Arrays.asList((String)null));
```

...or you can use Java's `Stream` API and filter out all `null` elements through `Objects.nonNull`.

```
stringList = stringList.stream().filter(Objects::nonNull)
                                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

***Neither of these options*** care about the length of the collection.